# "require if" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack

Here is what I have in my rack app

```
#rb file
require 'pry'
class .....

#GemFile
group :development do
    gem "pry"
    gem "pry-nav"
end
```

Of course, in production it causes an error. How do make a kind of "require if"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
require 'pry' if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can embed it inside a if block

according to docs Sinatra provides a environment variable
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Environments

```
if development?
 require 'pry'
end
```

wherever you need to use it.

this may not be the exact solution you may be looking for just a wild guess

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to write such method in Object or Kernel in your app:

```
def require_pry
  require 'pry' if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
end
```

After that you can call require_pry if you need it in your code. But I have doubts why it cannot be handled by Bundler, Bundle.require will require all gems needed for environment.